# How to switch between different implementation that implements same interface as a dependency for a service in nest js

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, nestjs, code-injection

Let's say we have SomeService that accepts Iprovider as it's dependency and I want to be able to use different implementation for Iprovider depending on which controller calls the SomeService. How is this achievable in nestjs?

Answer (score 3):

You can Use an `Injection Token`

Here is a sample code:

*This sample assumes you have set up a NestJS project. This is a simple form. Obviously real world implementation may or maynot differ*

**Provider Interface**

```
export interface IProvider{
  method();
}
```

**Implementations**

*Implementation 1*

```
import {IProvider} from '<path>';

//This token will be used to inject ProviderOne instance
export const ProviderOneToken = 'provider_one';

export class ProviderOne implements IProvider{
  public method(){
   console.log('ProviderOne');
 }
}
```

*Implementation 2*

```
import {IProvider} from '<path>';

//This token will be used to inject ProviderTwo instance
export const ProviderTwoToken = 'provider_two';

export class ProviderTwo implements IProvider{
  public method(){
   console.log('ProviderTwo');
 }
}
```

Now in `App module`,

```
//Imports....

@Module({
 providers:[
    {provide:ProviderOneToken, useClass:ProviderOne},
    {provide:ProviderTwoToken, useClass:ProviderTwo},
    // The service we are going to test the token based
    // injection
    ServiceToInject
  ]
})
export class AppModule{
}
```

`ServiceToInject`

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from '@nestjs/common'
//Imports....

@Injectable()
export class ServiceToInject{
  constructor(@Inject(ProviderOneToken) private readonly provider:IProvider){
 }
 public serviceMethod(){
  //Calls method of ProviderOne instance(service)
 // Logs = 'ProviderOne'
  this.provider.method();
 }
}
```

Now swap out the token,

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from '@nestjs/common'
//Imports....

@Injectable()
export class ServiceToInject{
  // Changed provider token inside @Inject(<Here>).Rest are same
  constructor(@Inject(ProviderTwoToken) private readonly provider:IProvider){
 }
 public serviceMethod(){
  //Calls method of ProviderTwo instance(service)
  // Logs = 'ProviderTwo'
  this.provider.method();
 }
}
```

Both token in same service:

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from '@nestjs/common'
//Imports....

@Injectable()
export class ServiceToInject{
  constructor(@Inject(ProviderTwoToken) private readonly providerTwo:IProvider,
@Inject(ProviderOneToken) private readonly providerOne:IProvider
){
 }
 public serviceMethod(){
  //Calls method of ProviderOne instance(service)
  // Logs = 'ProviderOne'
  this.providerOne.method();
  //Calls method of ProviderTwo instance(service)
  // Logs = 'ProviderTwo'
  this.providerTwo.method();
 }
}
```

**Update :**

The `ServiceToInject` can be controller as well.

`ControllerOne`

```
@Controller('one')
export class ControllerOne{
 constructor(@Inject(ProviderOneToken) private readonly providerOne:IProvider){}
 @Get()
 public getOne(){
 //Logs - 'ProviderOne'
 this.provider.method();
}
 
}
```

`ControllerTwo`

```
@Controller('two')
export class ControllerTwo{
 constructor(@Inject(ProviderTwoToken) private readonly providerOne:IProvider){}
 @Get()
 public getTwo(){
 //Logs - 'ProviderTwo'
 this.provider.method();
}
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question. Let's say the implementation of provider depends on the controller that's calling class ServiceToInject, for example if controllerOne is calling class ServiceToInject then ProviderOne should be used and ProviderTwo should be used while class ServiceToInject is called by controllerTwo. How do we go about this?

Comment: The easiest way to go about this is to pass an argument to the serviceToInject method and have the method handle it with if else. In most cases that might do it